# Oracle "replace" function alternative in PostgreSQL with 2 arguments?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

```sql
Select REPLACE('123123tech', '123')
  From Dual;
```

Above is Oracle code but when I am going to find its alternative in PostgreSQL can't find a suitable function for that. PostgreSQL `REPLACE` function takes 3 arguments. I want a function who can take 2 arguments. Any solution ?

Comment: Oracle's REPLACE function also takes three arguments but the third is optional, which means that in your case, you want to remove the characters `123` from the source string. PostgreSQL has the same function but the third argument is not optional. So, as far as I can tell, there is no 2 argument function solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this in Postgresql is `Select REPLACE('123123tech', '123','')`.

Best regards,
Bjarni